# com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time

Tags: azure, exception, containers, storage, disk

Facing this Azure issue -

```
Storage exception occurred while getting storage containers and disks.

    com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.
```

Could anyone please help me get past through this issue ? Thanks.

Researched in google, but could not find any right way to fix this.

Comment: Could you please provide more details where you got this error?

Comment: Hi @HariKrishna, thanks for your prompt reply. Below is the code block where we are facing NullPointerException:- com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine--> executeWithRetry()

 if (task.getResult().getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED || task.getResult().getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_VERSION
                            || translatedException.getErrorCode().equals(StorageErrorCodeStrings.INVALID_BLOB_TYPE)) {
                        throw translatedException;
                    }

translatedException.getErrorCode() is null.

Comment: @HariKrishna please find more details here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/32207 , this has screenshots shared.